# Recommender system for matching user input keywords to objects that have different keywords assigned to them (and getting the matching weights)

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, recommender-system

I'm looking for some tips in the right direction as to what to look into for this recommender system:

We have a predefined set of objects, each with a few keywords assigned to them. We can call the total universe of these keywords as set K1.

Given user input into this system of a few english keywords (these may or may not be in set K1), I would like to output the top N closest matching objects whose keywords most closely match the input keywords. I would also like to get which keywords from K1 provided the most signal for this output value.

I'm just looking for someone to point me in the right direction as to what to look into for building a system like this.

**UPDATE**

Adding an example here:

Say we have the following object to keyword mappings:

Obj1 -> "Technology", "Innovation", "Gaming", "Community"
Obj2 -> "Finance", "Traditional", "Automotive"

Now a user inputs the following keyword: "Semiconductor"

I'm looking for the expected output to be "Obj1", and have some sort of ranking of which keywords for that object matched the closest, for example:

- Technology - 90/100 Match Score
- Innovation - 75/100 Match Score
- Gaming - 35/100 Match Score
- Community - 15/100 Match Score

Comment: Some aspects are unclear to me. What do you expect to happen query contains a keyword not in the universe K1? I am not certain you really need a recommendar system here (or even statistics at all). Your question could possibly profit from some toy examples.

Comment: @NikolasRieble Added an example. The reason I am thinking about recommender systems is because this problem kind of reminds me of how search engines recommend top results. I'm hoping there is a similar pattern we could use here.

Answer (score 2):

As you do not mention training data in your question, I assume none exists.

Thus I suggest to investigate word embedding such as [GloVe](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/). Note that this is just an example, there might be other, more up to date or better fitting word embeddings.

Given such a word embedding, you could then compute the distance between one keyword / tag to another (the query keywords) and use the distance to identify the closest match.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the direction! I'll look into it a bit and report back.